# Displaying images within a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, resources

I know this question has been asked before, but I have gone over all the solutions I could find and cannot make any of them work for me. I have a program in Eclipse that I am trying to export to an executable jar file. It is the first time I have done this. When I execute the jar, my program images do not show up. So I did some research and found I need to load them as resources, but I cannot seem to make it work.

Here is the code I was using to load the images without the jar:

```
private void initComponents()
{

    // create an enterprise icon and make it invisible
    enterpriseIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("res/enterprise1.png"));
    enterpriseIcon.setVisible(false);
}
```

I have all my images in a folder named res in my root project directory, and I told Eclipse to put this folder in the build path.

When the images wouldn't show up when running the jar file, I tried the following:

```
enterpriseIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/enterprise1.png")));
```

and

```
  enterpriseIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/res/enterprise.png"))));
```

However, when either of these is run from within Eclipse, I get a null pointer exception. (I tried a few other things as well, but the above were the only solutions I thought I understood.)

Any help getting this to work would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using getClass().getResource("/res/enterprise1.png")

Comment: Sorry for leaving it out, but that was actually what I tried first. I corrected my post to include it.

Comment: Have you tried the path "rez/enterprise1.png"? Are you sure the I age exists within the jar and that the path is correct

Comment: It looks like the /res folder with the images is not in the jar. I did tell Eclipse to use this folder as a source folder. How do I make it put it in the jar?

Comment: I had similar issues and eventually solved it by using `getResourceAsStream` instead of `getResource`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Class#getResource` to get the URL of your image inside the jar file

```
enterpriseIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/enterprise1.png")));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I already tried that as well. That was supposed to be the first example of failed code in my post, but I copied and pasted the wrong thing. Anyway, it gives me the same null pointer exception. I will correct my post.

Comment: @user2765703 Verify that the image is inside the jar. The method returns `null` if it couldn't find anything at the specified path. You can try variations such as removing the leading `/` though I don't think that should work.

Comment: I found that I can make it work if I put the images in the /bin folder of my main project and change the code to enterpriseIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("enterprise1.png"))); However, I would like to be able to use my /res folder instead if possible. I did tell Eclipse to put it on the build path. Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209621/java-jar-export-images-folder-is-wrong. It actually looks like you should be able to just say `enterprise1.png` or something if you've declared your `res` folder as a source folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This works well for me :)

```
private void initComponents() {
    try {
        BufferedImage icon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/enterprise1.png"));
        frame.setIconImage(icon);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue till yesterday. I have got a fix for this. Let me share it with you.

- In your Eclipse, go to your Project name.
- Right your project name.
- New -> Source file/folder
- Name this Source file/folder as images
- Now on your local machine go to the Eclipse workspace where your project
  is physically present.
- Copy ALL your images into the newly created
  'images' folder right there only.
- Now go back to Eclipse.
- Right click on your Project -> Refresh
- Now, wherever you are using images in your .java files , go to those lines and prefix the image location with images/

Example : XXX xxx = XXXX (example.jpg)
Change it with .... XXX xxx = XXXX (images/example.jpg)

BOOM !!
The images will be shown when you run the .jar file.

NOTE : Do not run the .jar file from cmd using java -jar AppName.jar
Instead, just double click the .jar file and you will be seeing the images.

If it works for you, kindly upvote. :)